# Pass a list to a function to act as multiple arguments

Tags: python, list, parameter-passing

In a function that expects a list of items, how can I pass a Python list item without getting an error?

```
my_list = ['red', 'blue', 'orange']
function_that_needs_strings('red', 'blue', 'orange') # works!
function_that_needs_strings(my_list) # breaks!
```

Surely there must be a way to expand the list, and pass the function `'red','blue','orange'` on the hoof? I think this is called 'unpacking'.

Answer (score 365, accepted):

```
function_that_needs_strings(*my_list) # works!
```

You can read all about it here: [Unpacking Argument Lists - The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

Answer (score 51):

Yes, you can use the `*args` (splat) syntax:

```
function_that_needs_strings(*my_list)
```

where `my_list` can be any iterable; Python will loop over the given object and use each element as a separate argument to the function.

See the [call expression documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls).

There is a keyword-parameter equivalent as well, using two stars:

```
kwargs = {'foo': 'bar', 'spam': 'ham'}
f(**kwargs)
```

and there is [equivalent syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters) for specifying catch-all arguments in a function signature:

```
def func(*args, **kw):
    # args now holds positional arguments, kw keyword arguments
```

Answer (score 19):

Since Python 3.5 you can unpack unlimited amount of `list`s.

[PEP 448 - Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-448-additional-unpacking-generalizations)

So this will work:

```
a = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
b = ['5', '6']
function_that_needs_strings(*a, *b)
```

Comment: how can I do the same with python 2.7 or 3.4?

Comment: @answerSeeker not efficient, but `function_that_needs_strings(*(a+b))`

Comment: wow, can't believe You couldn't before that.

Comment: @answerSeeker more efficient: `function_that_needs_strings(*itertools.chain(a, b))`