# printing tab-separated values of a list

Tags: python, printing, python-3.x

Here's my current code:

```
print(list[0], list[1], list[2], list[3], list[4], sep = '\t')
```

I'd like to write it better. But

```
print('\t'.join(list))
```

won't work because list elements may numbers, other lists, etc., so `join` would complain.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
print(*list, sep='\t')
```

Note that you shouldn't use the word `list` as a variable name, since it's the name of a builtin type.

Comment: seems like an elegant way.. but can someone explain what *list does here?

Comment: @olala it's called unpacking a list. Making it into list[0], list[1], etc. like he did in the question. See for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480184/unpack-a-list-in-python)

Comment: for that to work in python 2.7 don't forget to `from __future__ import print_function` as the first line in your file

Comment: how to assign this value to a variable ?

Answer (score 36):

```
print('\t'.join(map(str,list)))
```

Answer (score 12):

```
print('\t'.join([str(x) for x in list]))
```