# Python how to use map() to split list into sublists?

Tags: python, reduce

I have this function to split iterables into sublists by length, the fill values, and the direction of fill :

```
def split(v,size,fill=0,direction='right'):
    if size == 0: return []
    lenv = len(v)
    count = lenv/size
    remainder = lenv%size
    result = []
    for i in range(0,lenv-remainder,size):
            result.append(v[i:i+size])
    if remainder > 0:
            if direction == 'right':
                    result.append(v[count*size:] + [fill] * (size-remainder))
            else:
                    result.append([fill] * (size-remainder) + v[count*size:])
    return result
```

Because I like one liners I want to rewrite it with map, but I don't understand how to. I have this so far :

```
def j1(a,b): 
        return a + b 

def j2(a,b): 
        return b 

def split2(v,size,fill=0): 
        map(j1,(x for x in map(j2,v)))
```

I have no idea. Any hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are thinking too much. This problem can be aptly handled using the [grouper recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) without using `map`

```
def split1(v,size,fill=0,direction='right'):
    result = list(izip_longest(*[iter(l)]*size, fillvalue=fill))
    if direction == 'left':
        result[-1] = result[-1][::-1]
    return result
```

Explanation:

- [iter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter): This function converts a sequence to an iterable. Iterables are self consumable and has only one method, `next` which returns the next element from the iterable, moving from left to right.
- `[iter(l)]*size`: Creates a list of `size` iterables
- [* (Kleene star)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480184/unpack-a-list-in-python): This operator is used to unpack a list or tuple
- [izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest): Transposed the elements. For shorter sequences, it is filled by filled value
- `result[-1] = result[-1][::-1]`: If the direction is `left` reverse the last sequence

Another possible popular solution without grouper is

```
def split2(v,size,fill=0,direction='right'):
    result = [v[i:i+size] for i in range(0,len(v),size)]
    result[-1] = result[-1] + [fill] * (size - len(result[-1]))
    if direction == 'left':
        result[-1] = result[-1][::-1]
    return result
```

Explanation:

- Used Python's [Extended Slice](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html). Sequence Slicing has the following syntax `[start: end: stride]`
- Python Range returns a list (in Py2.x) and a range object (in Py 3.x) as a sequence/iterable , starting from `start`, ending at `end` and stepping `stride` elements. Similar to `(for int i = start; i < stop; i+= stride)`
- `[fill] * (size - len(result[-1]))`: Generates `(size - len(result[-1]))` `fill` elements as a list. If `(size - len(result[-1]))` is <=0 it generates an empty list
- `result[-1] = result[-1] + [fill] * (size - len(result[-1]))` - Update the last sequence with the fill value
- `result[-1] = result[-1][::-1]`: If the direction is `left` reverse the last sequence

Comment: I like that it is concise. Could you explain the * unpacking a little bit?

Comment: one thing you overlooked was the reversal actually reverses the original sequence of the list, as well as the side which the fills are applied on. So I am going to edit your answer to include the intended function!