# Purpose of the * operator in builtin zip function?

Tags: python

This seems to be a good way to get the transpose of a matrix. But I'm not sure what exactly is happening when the * operator is invoked. Can someone unpack that?

```
 >>> zip(*[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
 [(1,4), (2,5), (3,6)]
```

Comment: It's list unpacking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480184/unpack-a-list-in-python

Comment: It is covered in the tutorial: [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). Python 3.5 implements [PEP 0448 -- Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/).

Comment: I tried actually searching for this and found a chain of duplicates so long I gave up looking for the first one. Please search first. This **exact question** has literally been answered dozens of times here.

Comment: Can someone *unpack* that? Ha!

Comment: It's the splat operator. Basically, it passes the contents of the lists as arguments.

Comment: So `zip(*[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])` is the same `zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6])`

Comment: Haha @MalikBrahimi I'm glad I'm not the only one who laughed at that.

Answer (score 2):

The `*` operator is used to unpack the values, when using that in the list of lists like - `zip(*[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])` , it unpacks the outer list, and hence the actual input to `zip` function looks like - `zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6])` . And when they get zipped you get the result - `[(1,4), (2,5), (3,6)]`