# Unpack list as key in dictionary -- Python 3.4

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm attempting to sort two values drawn from the indices of a list so that the key in a dictionary is alway some pair of values (x,y) such that x < y.

Given, for example:

```
a = [['0', '1', '.5'], ['3', '1', '.7'], ['18','16','.4']]
```

I would like d[(16, 18)] = .4, with all numbers in the key turned into integers in order from smallest to largest, and the value as a float.

Here's what I've tried:

```
a = [['0', '1', '.5'], ['3', '1', '.7'], ['18','16','.4']]

d = {}
for i in a:
    b = sorted([int(i[0]), int(i[1])])
    d[*b] = float(i[2])
```

I read about unpacking a list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480184/unpack-a-list-in-python) and thought I'd give it a go, but I'm getting a SyntaxEror on the asterisk. Help?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by unpacking? What is your end result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered, you can't use *-unpacking within an index like that.  But your code should work if you use `tuple(b)` instead of `*b` (we can't use `b` itself, because lists aren't hashable and so can't be used as dictionary keys.)

```
>>> for i in a:
        b = sorted([int(i[0]), int(i[1])])
        d[tuple(b)] = float(i[2])
...     
>>> d
{(0, 1): 0.5, (1, 3): 0.7, (16, 18): 0.4}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a tuple as an index to a dict, but it is not a parameter, so the asterisk syntax doesn't apply:

```
a = [['0', '1', '.5'], ['3', '1', '.7'], ['18','16','.4']]

d = {}

for (x,y,z) in a:
    d[tuple(sorted(int(i) for i in (x, y)))] = float(z)

print(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```py
>>> d = {(min(x, y), max(x, y)): float(z) for x, y, z in a}
>>> d
{('16', '18'): 0.4, ('0', '1'): 0.5, ('1', '3'): 0.7}
>>> for (x, y), z in d.items():
...     print('%s, %s: %f' % (x, y, z))
```