# Turning a list into a list of lists Python 3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, text, text-files

I have a list file made up of car details.

e.g.

```
1000001 Volvo v8
1000002 Mazda 2.0
```

Comment: Can you show us these "variety of methods to split the list"? Or at least one of them.

Comment: while count2<length2:
 new.append(str.split(cars[count2]))
 count2=count2+1

Comment: @bobbyzamora - don't forget to "accept" an answer if you decide one answers your question

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you need to `split` each line; you can use a list comprehension, as follows

```
cars = [line.split() for line in open("Cars.txt")]
```

As mentioned in the comments; you want numerical representations of the numbers. To do this you need to convert the numerical columns into numbers. E.g.

```
for i in range(len(cars)):
    cars[i][0] = int(cars[i][0])
    cars[i][-1] = int(cars[i][-1])
```

Then e.g. `cars[0][0]` will be a number. 
Alternatively, if the numbers will always be positive integers, you can condense this to:

```
readline = lambda l: [int(n) if n.isdigit() else n for n in l.split()]
cars = [[ readline(line) for line in open("Cars.txt")]
```

For any more complicated datafile reading, you might want to use e.g. `pandas`.

**Generators**

As pointed out by zondo in the comments, you might consider using a `generator` instead, which doesn't load all the data into memory (instead "generating" each element when requested); this can be done by swapping `[]` for `()` in the comprehension:

```
cars = (line.split() for line in open("Cars.txt"))
```

Then you can still iterate over cars as you would a list, but you **can't** index into a generator, as you can a list.

Comment: As a note, you might want to use `()` instead of `[]` to save memory.  Of course, that won't necessarily work in all cases, but it can be advantageous.

Comment: @zondo: In this case the OP implied that they wanted a list at the end, (not a generator) - but a good comment in general.

Comment: I realize that he did say that, but he might not know about generators, so wouldn't know that they could be more efficient.

Comment: This is a method I've used. If I return the firs item i.e cars[0] it returns 1000001 Volvo 34000, I now need to able to access the 34000 and multiply it by a number and store/output that number

Comment: The index `-1` is used to access the end of a list, tuple, etc.

Comment: Did not know that, amazing :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a proper way to access all the information in the text file, you can simply define a class for it. And later fill it with information from the file. Here is an example implementation. I used [unpack operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480184/unpack-a-list-in-python) (*) here.

```
class Car(object):

    def __init__(self, id, name, price):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id + ' ' + self.name + ' ' + self.price


file = open("file.txt", 'r')
cars = [Car(*line.split()) for line in file]

for c in cars:
    print c
```

Or use generator expression if you have a really large file

```
cars = (Car(*line.split()) for line in file)
```

In both cases it prints,

```
1000001 Volvo 34000
1000002 Mazda 23000
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can store your results in a `list`, using the `split` function:

```
cars = []

with open("cars.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        cars.append(line.split())
```

If you want to be able to search quickly based on your unique ID, you might be better off using a dictionary.

Comment: This is the method I've used, and its fine, but I need to be able to actually get at the cost of each car and multiply it by a number. That's my mains struggle, I can't seem to actually get hold of that value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure python way:

```
text = '1000001 Volvo 34000 1000002 Mazda 23000'

# Split text into one list
l = text.split()

# Split list into list of list every 3rd element
l = [l[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(l), 3)]
print l
```

---

```
[['1000001', 'Volvo', '34000'], ['1000002', 'Mazda', '23000']]
```

Comment: FYI, originally the text was all on one line... if this is not the case after the question update, then this answer is not really correct...

Answer (score -1):

This could be done with a `regex` to produce a `list` of `tuple`s:

```
import re

text = '1000001 Volvo 34000 1000002 Mazda 23000'

l = re.findall(r'(\d+) (\w+) (\d+)', text)
print l
```

---

```
[('1000001', 'Volvo', '34000'), ('1000002', 'Mazda', '23000')]
```

If you really need a `list` of `list`s you can convert it:

```
l = [list(x) for x in l]
print l
```

---

```
[['1000001', 'Volvo', '34000'], ['1000002', 'Mazda', '23000']]
```

Comment: Why use regex instead of a simple split?  Since `.split()` is built into the Python language, can't we assume that it uses the most efficient approach?

Comment: Well it is one way to do it... you are correct `regex` is typically a performance hit... see my new [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36085911/2087463) for a pure python way to do it.

Comment: Regex is an advanced technique.  This OP is obviously not advanced at python, so I downvoted.

Comment: Why not?  He is asking for something that can be done simply.  Why introduce a more advanced approach that performs worse?

Comment: That is how one learns... they don't have to use it.  **I have learned about many new techniques thru someone's SO answers/comments that didn't help me at the moment but that I went to research later.**  It can be tucked away in the brain for when the input gets more complex and you *really* need a `regex` parser.

Comment: FYI, originally the text was all on one line... if this is not the case after the question update, then this answer is not really correct...

Comment: @joelgoldstick I would petition you to remove the downvote because of my comment above.  Questions and Answers are not just for the OP, *they are for posterity as well*! Especially if you think the OP is not advanced, I would argue that then you should want to expose them to small reproducible chunks of more advanced topics.  This keeps them curious and adds a little direction for self discovery.  At least for my self, SO has been a pedagogical  tool that is much more influential than getting the answer to one specific question.

Comment: I found it all very useful thank you, but at this very moment the simplest approach is always the best, and thanks to all of you I have advanced tremendously.