# Use lists inside a list with itertools.product

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I need to calculate the cartesian product of the elements of a few lists. It seems that the best way to do this is to use itertools, and in particular itertools.product. Now, the lists I want to use are themselves contained in a list, and I cannot just use the bigger list for itertools.product. I was wondering how I should extract the lists to make them usable with itertools.product.

Here is an example that shows the problem:

```
import itertools

elements=[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
product=itertools.product(elements)
print product
```

This prints [([1, 2],), ([3, 4],)]. What I wanted instead is something equivalent to the following but where I don't have to give all elements of "elements" singularly:

```
product=itertools.product(elements[0], elements[1])
print product
```

which prints [(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)].

Thanks.

Comment: Just use `itertools.product(*elements)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480184/unpack-a-list-in-python

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I didn't think of the word "unpack"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Unpack](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) the lists in your list with the star operator `*` to apply the product to your sublists.

```
product=list(itertools.product(*elements))
```