# psycopg2: use a list in a query without index rows

Tags: python, postgresql, list, python-2.7, psycopg2

I'm writing to a db using this query with various placeholders:

```
sql_write_ord = '''INSERT INTO rest_order_test (date_order, pos_line_id, pos_order_id, product_name, instructions, qty,
                partner_name, status, to_wait, to_floor) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'''

order= '2016-06-10 16:36:53'
newTable = [12821, 4421, 'Crudo MD', 'Y', Decimal('1.0'), 'Mesa 10', 'A fazer', 'N', '0']

cur.execute(sql_write_ord,[order, newTable[0], newTable[1], newTable[2], newTable[3], newTable[4], newTable[5], newTable[6], newTable[7], newTable[8]])
```

Is there any optimized solution like

```
cur.execute(sql_write_ord, ([order, newTable]))
```

without generating an 'IndexError: list index out of range'?

Comment: You can unpack a list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480184/unpack-a-list-in-python

Comment: if you suggested something like 'cur.execute(sql_write_ord, ([order], *newTable))' doesn't works (with a single line) with psycopg2, or I'm wrong? The solution proposed by alecxe fit perfectly.

Comment: Should be `order` instead of `[order]`

Comment: cur.execute(sql_write_ord, (order,*newTable)): SyntaxError: invalid syntax and I need [order] because will be a list. But the unpack is a good idea for another situation I have. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just concatenate the lists:

```
cur.execute(sql_write_ord, [order] + newTable)
```

Comment: Simple and elegant. Thanks.