# Extending list by adding element to special position

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to extend list by adding one element. Pos indicates where I should insert new element and also which value should be inserted (the value of element in original list)
F.e.

```
    ([1, 2, 3], 0) => [1, 1, 2, 3]
    ([1, 2, 3], 1) => [1, 2, 2, 3]
    ([1, 2, 3], 2) => [1, 2, 3, 3]
```

If pos is too high, I had to add 0 element to the end.

```
([1, 2, 3], 9) => [1, 2, 3, 0]
```

I have done so far:

```
def extend_list(numbers, pos):
    if pos > len(numbers) - 1:
        numbers.append(0)
        return numbers
    return numbers[:pos] + numbers[pos] + numbers[pos:]
```

But I get an error: `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list`
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Wrap `numbers[pos]` with square brackets

Comment: Also, you might want to check out `list.insert`.

Comment: `numbers[pos]` is a single value from the list, not itself a list. `[numbers[pos]]` would put it back in a list. Or use `numbers[pos:pos + 1]` to slice one element.

Comment: If updating the list *in place* is fine too, use `numbers.insert(pos, numbers[pos])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that numbers[pos] is an integer that you are trying to add to `numbers[:pos]` and `numbers[pos:]`, which are lists. A simple solution is to replace `return numbers[:pos] + numbers[pos] + numbers[pos:]` with `return numbers[:pos] + [numbers[pos]] + numbers[pos:]`

However, a shorter solution would be:

```
vals = [([1, 2, 3], 0), ([1, 2, 3], 1), ([1, 2, 3], 2)]
new_vals = [[*a[:b], a[b], *a[b:]] for a, b in vals]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3]]
```

In Python2:

```
import itertools
new_vals = [list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[c, c] if c == a[b] else [c] for c in a])) for a, b in vals]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3]]
```

Comment: Do include an explanation of what you are doing, and answer where the OP  went wrong.

Comment: what does *a mean @Ajax1234

Comment: got it, this might be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480184/unpack-a-list-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You could alternatively use the `.insert()` method to make the addition to the list, as I have done below. I also used an else statement instead of 2 return statements out of personal preference.

```
def extend_list(numbers, pos):
    if pos > len(numbers) - 1:
        numbers.append(0)
    else:
        numbers.insert(pos, numbers[pos])
    return numbers
```

In fact, due to the nature of lists in python as mutable objects, running this function will edit the original list, meaning the return statement here is unnecessary and the code functions fine without it.

```
def extend_list(numbers, pos):
    if pos > len(numbers) - 1:
        numbers.append(0)
    else:
        numbers.insert(pos, numbers[pos])

lst = [1,2,3]
extend_list(lst, 1)

## will print [1,2,2,3] ##
print(lst)
```