# "Slicing" a pair of numpy arrays based on values in one of them

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Conceptually, I have two lists of equal length, one containing `labels` and the other `data`. And so I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739048/how-to-slice-a-pair-of-lists-based-on-values-in-one-of-them), not realising that what I really had was two `numpy` arrays, not two lists.

What I do have is a folder containing images such as `cat_01.jpg`, `cat_02.jpg`, `dog_01.jpg`, `dog_02.jpg`, `dog_03.jpg`, `fish_01.jpg`, ..., `tiger_03.jpg`, `zebra_01.jpg` and `zebra_02.jpg`. I also have a successful program to read them in, parse a portion of each file name into a `labels` array, and the corresponding image data into my `data` array, so that I end up with something like:

```
>>> labels
array(['cat', 'cat', 'dog',  ..., 'tiger', 'zebra', 'zebra' ])
>>> type( data )
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> data[0][0][0]
array([78, 88, 98])
```

That makes sense - in each `sample` at (`column`, `row`), `data[ sample ][ row ][ column ]` represents an (R,G,B) data point.

I want to specify a search label such as `'dog'`, and (conceptually) use it to generate two "sub-lists" - the first containing all the (identical) matching labels in the `labels` list, and the other containing the associated image data from `data`. But rather than lists, I need to retain the original data format, in this case `numpy` arrays (but if there is a more general, data-insensitive approach, I'd love to know about it) . How can I do this?

**Update:** here's some specific test code to recreate the situation I am confronting, and with a sketch of a solution based on Stephen Rauch's answer:

```
import os, glob
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    # not critical to question

def load_image(file):
  data = np.asarray(Image.open(file),dtype="float")
  return data

MasterClass = ['cat','dog','fsh','grf','hrs','leo','owl','pig','tgr','zbr']
os.chdir('data\\animals')
filelist = glob.glob("*.jpg")

full_labels = np.array([MasterClass.index(os.path.basename(fname)[:3]) for fname in filelist])
full_images = np.array([load_image(fname) for fname in filelist])
# The following sketch a solution, but which leads to incompatible data types
# That is, the test_images differ from the full_images and/or so do the labels
# with regard to the data types involved.
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(label=list(full_labels),data=list(full_images)))
criteria = df['label'] == MasterClass.index('dog')
test_labels = np.array(df[criteria]['label'])
test_images = np.array(df[criteria]['data'])
```

Two notes:

- When originally I wrote that there were file names "such as" `tiger_03.jpg`, I was de-obfuscating reality. In truth the code above expects file names like `tgr03.jpg`, and the list of labels I end up working with is not even `['cat', 'cat', 'dog', ...]` but is instead a list of indices in the `MasterClass` list - that is, `[0, 0, 1, ...]`
- For test purposes the contents of the files don't actually matter, so long as they are valid (JPEG) images. You can easily test with a handful of (identical) files in a folder with a handful of different names.

The question is: how do I get `test_labels` and `test_images` to be in an identical format to the original `full_labels` and `full_images` but based on a selection `criteria` like the one sketched above? This code as it stands does not achieve this level of data compatibility - it does not achieve a strict "slice" function.

Comment: The important things about a numpy array are usually not the class and data, but the dtype and shape.

Comment: Can you uses pandas?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use pandas, it is VERY good at this sort of thing.

#### Code:

If you already have a dataframe, you can simply do:

```
# build a logical condition
have_dog = df['animal_label'] == 'dog'

# select the data when that condition is true
print(df[have_dog])
```

#### Test Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

animal_label = ['cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'dog', 'fish', 'fish', 'giraffe']
data = [0.3, 0.1, 0.9, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.8]
data = [np.array((x,) * 3) for x in data]

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(animal_label=animal_label, data=data))
print(df)

have_dog = df['animal_label'] == 'dog'
print(df[have_dog])
```

#### Results:

```
  animal_label             data
0          cat  [0.3, 0.3, 0.3]
1          cat  [0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
2          dog  [0.9, 0.9, 0.9]
3          dog  [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
4          dog  [0.4, 0.4, 0.4]
5         fish  [0.3, 0.3, 0.3]
6         fish  [0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
7      giraffe  [0.8, 0.8, 0.8]

  animal_label             data
2          dog  [0.9, 0.9, 0.9]
3          dog  [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
4          dog  [0.4, 0.4, 0.4]
```

Comment: In your example, one of the "conceptual" lists is an actual list - the `animal_labels`. In my case, both of the objects are `numpy` arrays. I think if you use `numpy_labels = np.asarray(animal_labels)` you get the situation I intend... but then I can't construct the DataFrame - every permutation of `df = pd.DataFrame(dict(labels=list(numpy_labels),data=data))` I have tried fails with a "data must be 1-dimensional" exception.

Comment: There are myriad ways to construct a data frame.  Dict is a but quick way if that is already the way your data is.  I am not fully understanding your data description, but pandas is VERY good at mapping to native numpy structures.  Primary point was just to show how to select dataframe rows based on a label match.

Comment: I can now construct the DataFrame using `pd.DataFrame(dict(labels=list(nump_labels),data=list(numpy_data)))` - you have interpreted my "conceptual" lists as actual lists of numpy arrays. There are only numpy arrays "acting" as lists in a conceptual sense.

Comment: Appreciate the pointer in the direction of pandas :-) My only remaining issues seem to be ensuring that the two arrays extracted from the DataFrame are identical in format to the two original numpy arrays I had. Working on it...

Comment: I have updated question to include test code, partly based on this answer - hopefully that will make things clearer :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, this would be done by slicing like this:

```
selector = 'fish'
matching_labels = labels[labels==selector]
matching_data = data[labels==selector]
```

Alternatively, you could use the approach from the answer in your previous question and make the list `alist` a numpy array by `alist = numpy.array(alist)`

Comment: The data is not labeled, so your last line would not work. The two conceptual "lists" are completely separate - they need to be zipped, cross-referenced, etc

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Stephen Rauch's answer to my earlier simpler question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48739160/1099237), it is possible to solve this as follows:

```
# assume full_labels and full_images exist as per test code in updated question
tuples = (x for x in zip(list(full_labels),list(full_images)) if x[0] == MasterClass.index('dog'))
xlabels,ximages = map(list, zip(*tuples))
test_labels = np.array(xlabels)
test_images = np.array(ximages)
```