# Pass a list to function with variable number of args in python

Tags: python

I have to write a simple function that takes variable number of arguments and prints the sum, something simple like(ignoring error checks):

```
def add(*params):
    sum = 0
    for num in params:
        sum += num
    print(sum)
```

I have to call the script and give it arguments that will then be used in the function. I get these arguments like this:

```
import sys
sys.argv[1:]
```

But that's an array and sending it to `add` would just mean passing 1 argument that is a list. I'm new to Python so maybe all of this sounds stupid, but is there any way to pass these arguments to the function properly?

Comment: `add(*sys.argv[1:])`

Comment: you now about builtin `sum()` I assume? `add()` is already a function too for adding two values, so it's a bad name choice here

Comment: @Chris_Rands I have to write the function myself for a small assignment. And yeah I named them in my language just wrote the english version here, didn't know add was already a thing but the editor highlights these stuff so I know not to use keywords.

Comment: `def my_sum(` would be better IMO, but it's a small point

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, just unpack the list using the same `*args` syntax you used when defining the function.

```
my_list = [1,2,3]
result = add(*my_list)
```

Also, be aware that `args[1:]` contains strings. Convert these strings to numbers first with

```
numbers = [float(x) for x in args[1:]]
```

or

```
numbers = map(float, args[1:]) # lazy in Python 3
```

before calling `add` with `*numbers`.

Short version without your `add` function:

```
result = sum(map(float, args[1:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) syntax:

```
def add(*params):
    sum = 0
    for num in params:
        sum += num
    print(sum)

add(*[1,2,3])
add(*sys.argv[1:])
```

Here's [another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480184/unpack-a-list-in-python) covering the topic