# matrix 90 degree clockwise rotation using list in python

Tags: python, list, matrix

I'm trying to rotate a 3*3 matrix clockwise 90 degrees in python.
I've identified that element at [ i ][ j ] goes to [ j ][ new_i ].
Here new_i depends upon the previous i, so i made a function for it called circular subtraction.

if i is 0 then new_i is 2

if i is 1 then new_i is 1

if i is 2 then new_i is 0

after execution, it gave me unexpected results.

I've printed everything that is happening in each iteration.
I am unable to figure out how some elements are getting replaced with different ones.

```
'''
1 2 3                       7 4 1
4 5 6  rotate 90 degrees    8 5 2
7 8 9                       9 6 3


'''

def circular_subtraction(i):
    new_i = i 
    if(i==0):
        new_i = 2
    elif(i==1):
        new_i = 1
    elif(i==2):
        new_i = 0
    return new_i


def rotate_clock(matrix):
    new_matrix = matrix

for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix)):
        new_i = circular_subtraction(i)
        new_matrix[j][new_i] = matrix[i][j]
        print("New element added from {},{} to {},{} ::: {} to {}".format(i+1,j+1,j+1,new_i+1,matrix[i][j],new_matrix[j][new_i]))

for each_row in new_matrix:
    print(each_row)




matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
print("Length of the matrix : ",len(matrix))
for each_row in matrix:
    print(each_row)
print()
matrix = rotate_clock(matrix)
```

the input matrix was

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

The expected result was:

```
[7, 4, 1]
[8, 5, 2]
[9, 6, 3]
```

Result is:

```
[7, 4, 1]
[2, 5, 2]
[1, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Please try to point out the mistake in the above code. I know it can be done with numpy very easily, but I wanted to try it manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the numpy rot90 function for this: [np.rot90](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html)

```
mat = [[1, 2, 3], [4,5,6,], [7,8,9]]
np.rot90(mat, k=1, axes=(1,0))
```

k - indicates number of rotations
axes - indicates the direction of rotation

**Output**

```
array([[7, 4, 1],
   [8, 5, 2],
   [9, 6, 3]])
```

### The issue in your code

The code is missing indents (but assuming they are correct)
the line :

```
new_matrix = matrix
```

assigns a new reference to the matrix variable.
In python the default isn't copy by value. 
You can use deep copy function : [copy.deepcopy(x[, memo])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)

```
import copy

def rotate_clock(matrix):
    new_matrix = copy.deepcopy(matrix)
```

**OR**

```
def rotate_clock(matrix):
    new_matrix = [row[:] for row in matrix]
```

Otherwise, each change you make to new_matrix is being done in the original matrix as well. (since new_matrix is just a reference to matrix)

Comment: Thanks. That's what I wanted.

Answer (score 9):

You could do something like this:

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3],
          [4, 5, 6],
          [7, 8, 9]]

rotated = [list(reversed(col)) for col in zip(*matrix)]

for row in rotated:
    print(*row)
```

**Output**

```
7 4 1
8 5 2
9 6 3
```

The `for col in zip(*matrix)` gets the column of the matrix, once you have the columns you need to reverse them using `list(reversed(col))`, then use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to put all together:

```
rotated = [list(reversed(col)) for col in zip(*matrix)]
```

The above list comprehension is equivalent to the following less *pythonic* for loop:

```
rotated = []
for col in zip(*matrix):
    rotated.append(list(reversed(col)))
```

**Further**

1. Documentation on [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), [reversed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) and [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list).
2. The notation `*matrix` is known as tuple unpacking, more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480184/unpack-a-list-in-python).

Comment: so we rotate each column and then convert it into a row?

Comment: Yes, you get each column, reverse it and convert it into a row.

Comment: That's amazing.

Comment: how to do it anti-clockwise?

Answer (score 2):

In very simple python, this code works:

```
def rotate_matrix(a):
    b = []
    i = len(a)-1
    while i>=0:
        for j in range(0, len(a)):
            if (len(b) < (j+1)):
                b.append([a[i][j]])
            else:
                b[j].append(a[i][j])
        i -= 1
    return b
```

I printed b. That looked like this:
`[[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]`

Answer (score 1):

[`numpy.rot90`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html) could come handy as well:

```
import numpy as np

a = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]
a_rot = np.rot90(a, k=3).tolist()
for row in a_rot:
  print(row)
```

Output

```
[7, 4, 1]
[8, 5, 2]
[9, 6, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

A general method to rotate the `Matrix`, irrespective of shape.

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[1, 2, 3, 33], [4, 5, 6, 66], [7, 8, 9, 99]])
A
array([[ 1,  2,  3, 33],
       [ 4,  5,  6, 66],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 99]])

rotated_A=np.zeros((len(A[0]),len(A)))
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(A[0])):
        rotated_A[j][len(A)-1-i]=A[i][j]
rotated_A
array([[  7.,   4.,   1.],
       [  8.,   5.,   2.],
       [  9.,   6.,   3.],
       [ 99.,  66.,  33.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to rotate any matrix would be

```
import copy
def rotateImage(a):
 out = copy.deepcopy(a)
 x = 0;
 y = 0;
 for i in a:
  l = len(i)
  for j in i:
   out[y][x+l-1] = j
   y += 1
   if(y == l):
    y=0
  x -= 1
 return(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally all solution are for square matrix,
Below one will for any matrix:

```
mat = [[1, 2, 3, 5],
     [5, 6, 7, 1],
     [9, 10, 11, 8],
     [4, 7, 4, 3]]
 
def rotate_matrix(a):
    b = []
    i = len(a)-1
    while i>=0:
        if len(a) == len(a[-1]):
            for j in range(0, len(a)):
                print(j)
                if (len(b) < (j+1)):
                    b.append([a[i][j]])
                    print(b)
                else:
                    b[j].append(a[i][j])
                    print(b)
            i -= 1
        else:
            for j in range(0, len(a)+1):
                print(j)
                if (len(b) < (j+1)):
                    b.append([a[i][j]])
                    print(b)
                else:
                    b[j].append(a[i][j])
                    print(b)
            i -= 1
    return b
    
print(rotate_matrix(mat))
```