# Returning 2 values in a function

Tags: python

In a nutshell, I'm trying to implement the following:

```
def function_one(value):
...
return a, b

def function_two(a, b):
...
```

And when I try

```
function_two(function_one(value))
```

I get an error message:
"function_two() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'"

Is there a way to make this work as intended?
Thanks!

Comment: You need to unpack your tuple: `function_two(*function_one(value))`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unpack a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480184/unpack-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to unpack the tuple you return into separate arguments:

```
function_two(*function_one(value))
```

Another option would be changing `function_two` to accept a single argument and then unpack it inside the function or use it as-is. Whether this is a good idea or not depends on the context.