# Initialize python attributes from list

Tags: python

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

Case 1:
Obj1 = C(1,2)
print Obj1.a
print Obj1.b

Case 2:
l= [1,2]
Obj2 = C(l)
print Obj2.a
print Obj2.b
```

I want to initialize the object of a class with the list passed as initializer as shown in case 2 but that shows syntax error . 
Is there any way to do this in python ?

I found out I can use the unpacking here. Thanks for the answer.
Can I do some thing like this by combining both of these things
I know i just can append one more number and pass it to initialize object but is there a way to combine both these things ?

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

l= [1,2]
Obj2 = C(*l,3)
```

Comment: Use unpacking: `Obj2 = C(*l)`

Comment: Please see here for an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480184/unpack-a-list-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [unpack](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) operator `*`

The both are strictly equivalent:

```
Obj1 = C(1,2)
Obj1 = C(*[1,2])
```

Comment: Please check for duplicates before answering.

Comment: I understand this is a duplicate, but actually the OP just did not know about this operator :). But thanks for pointing out, and I should definitely link to other questions
I will remove this answer soon

Comment: Yes, you're right, the OP did not know about the operator. But now that this is a duplicate question there is a link at the top for everyone to see. Please keep this answer here so that others can see this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

you can unpack it, by `*`

```
l = [1, 2]
Obj2 = C(*l)
print(Obj2.a)
print(Obj2.b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, either you unpack outside or inside:

Inide:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, l):
        self.a, self.b = l
C([1,2])
```

Outside:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
C(*[1, 2])
```