# How do I make a new array from values and arrays, without the new array containing an array

Tags: python

I have these variables:

```
x = 1
y = [2, 3, 4]
z = 5
```

I want to add them all to a new array (something like this):

```
a = [x, y, z]
```

Now `a` is `[1, [2, 3, 4], 5]`

However, I want `a` to be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5`]

What's the most concise way to accomplish that?

Comment: `a = [x, y, *z]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480184/unpack-a-list-in-python 
This is effectively a duplicate

Comment: @MarkMeyer Thank you, that works.  I didn't know you could do `*z`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert `x` and `z` into lists and then chain them all together like this;

```
a = [x] + y + [z]
```

Or in [Python 3.5+](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/), you can unpack `y` as you build the list, like this:

```
a = [x, *y, z]
```