# How to call a method with an array as transfer parameter

Tags: python

How can I call a method with array as transform param? Like

```
my_array = [a, b]
pipeline.make_pipeline(my_array)
```

So if I write

```
pipeline.make_pipeline(my_array[0], my_array[1])
```

it works.

a and b are objects from sklearn.

I tried to convert the array to string and eval it:

```
pipeline_string = eval((', '.join(map(str, my_array))).replace("\n", ""))
pipeline.make_pipeline(pipeline_string)
```

To change or add a function in `make_pipeline` is no option

Thanks

Comment: Is [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) what you're looking for? If so this is probably [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480184/unpack-a-list-in-python).

Comment: `foo(*array)` to unpack array. and `foo(**_dict_)` to unpack dictionary.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. It's impossible to post a _serious_ answer without knowing (at least) what `pipeline.make_pipeline` expects as arguments. If it comes from a 3rd part lib, please mention it explicitely in your question (NOT in a comment), preferably with a link to the relevant doc. Else post the function or method definition (at least the signature).