# Extract individual values from numpy array into a list

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to extract the values from a numpy array and place the individual entries into a list.

For example, if I have the following list:

```
import numpy as np
x = 1
problem_variable = np.array(['a', 'b'], dtype='<U9')
z = 2
mylist = [x, problem_variable , z]
# [1, array(['a', 'b'], dtype='<U9'), 2]
```

How do I get the result

```
[1, 'a', 'b', 2]
```

I do not know the length of `problem_variable` before hand so cannot hard code `problem_variable[0]`, `problem_variable[1]` etc.

The following does what I want but I am sure that I am missing the appropriate way to break the array apart. Thanks.

```
result = []
result.append(x)
for i in problem_variable: result.append(i)
result.append(z)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can unpack your array:

```
mylist = [x, *problem_variable , z]
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you point me to some docs for `*` : i see this: https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists . edit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480184/unpack-a-list-in-python gives example and refs

Comment: you may have a lool over: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/

Comment: Thank you kederrac

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `numpy`: you can use [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to concatenate the input objects along first axis:

```
np.r_[x, problem_variable, z]
# array(['1', 'a', 'b', '2'], dtype='<U9')
```

---

Comparing performance on larger lists:

```
problem_var = np.concatenate([problem_variable]*10000, axis=0)

%timeit np.r_[x, problem_var, z]
# 143 µs ± 19.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit np.hstack((x, problem_var , z))
# 553 µs ± 55.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit [x, *problem_var.tolist() , z]
# 502 µs ± 42.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit [x, *problem_var , z]
# 6.46 ms ± 215 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you! thats what i was looking for. Do you  know what would be a good search term for me to use for this please as I was finding anything appropriate.

Comment: I supose a good place to start is always the docs. Here reading on the different slicing methods should help, see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: Thanks Yatu, this actually fits my use case better as I am then coercing the list to an array (great SO mind reading skills there!) but I'll mark kederrac's as it gives the results format in the question.

Comment: Note that arrays have a `tolist()` method, which you can use to get a list back from the `array` @user2957945

Comment: Added the timings also @user2957945

Comment: That's really great. Appreciate it Yatu . So working with arrays is much faster

Comment: In the general case and if used properly yes @user2957945 , much faster

Comment: `[x, *problem_var.tolist() , z]` improves the time of the unpacking approach.  `arr.tolist()` is much faster than the iterative `list(arr)`.

Comment: Indeed it does! Didn't expect the difference to be so large because of using the list constructor @hpaulj

Answer (score 1):

You can use [np.hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html), which can stack arrays in sequence horizontally,

```
np.hstack((x, problem_variable , z))

# ['1' 'a' 'b' '2']
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham; and this also retuns an array which is actually what i want for my use case.