# convert a list of integers into comma seperated integers

Tags: python-3.x

Input : [12,13,14,15]

O/p : 12,13,14,15

O/p should be int

Any suggestions on how to i/p a list of integers and get the o/p as integers but without the square braces?

Comment: Output should a string? Can you show what you have tried already?

Comment: Is the input a string with brackets or is it an actual Python list?  Is your output  a string or a series of integers (e.g. a Python list, tuple, numpy array)? Showing some code would also clarify that.

Comment: There is no such thing as "comma-separated integers." Do you expect a string of integers separated by commas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to this is to use "*" in print and using separator as ",".

The default separator is " " (Space).

```
lst = [12,13,14,15]
print(*lst,sep=",")
```

Comment: can you give a link to documentation for * please ? I have never seen * used like this

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3480184/8565438

Comment: I think this would be helpful: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Answer (score 0):

if you want in one string

```
l=[12,13,14,15]
print(','.join(l))
```

OR

```
l=[12,13,14,15]
for i in l[:-1]:
    print(i,end=',')
print(l[-1])
```

However while printing data type does not matter

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not really clear about the output, but if you want a string as output, you can do like this :

```
lst = [12,13,14,15]
str1 = ''.join(str(e)+',' for e in lst)
l = len(str1)-1
str1 = str1[:l]
```

then you can do what you want with `str1` (print it ect...)

Comment: or `','.join(str(e) for e in lst)`, that is the purpose of join

Comment: @SajanGohil WARNING : your way to do works, but you have to remove `l = len(str1)-1` and `str1 = str1[:l]` or the last digit will disappear !

Comment: that's the whole point, if you use join that way, you don't need extra processing

Comment: yup, but I prefer to mention it (just in case somebody else read too fast ^^)

Comment: You should not answer a question that is not clear to you.

Comment: I disagree with you @DYZ , I prefer to be wrong because I misunderstood and ask precisions than let somebody without any help because he has a hard time being understood. I don't pretend to have all answers, but if I can give a good idea and help, I do my best. (And if my answer is not suitable it will be ignored and will eventually be relegated to the bottom of the thread).