# What is the significance of the zip function?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, data-manipulation

Consider the following code snippet:

```
plt.plot(*zip(X[j], X[i]), color='black')
```

Why we've used asterisk before zip in the parameter of the plot method?

Comment: Are you aware of the asterisk as an [unpacking operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3480184/2550406)?

Comment: is your question about `zip` function (as stated in the title) or about `*` operator?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists