# How to append strings with tab characters to a list and print them also with tab characters?

Tags: python

I want to append a string with a tab character to a list. Then, when I print the list, I want to be able to get the same output when I do the print(string).

For example:

```
list1 = []
string = "Names:\tLucas"
print(list1)
print(string)
```

The output:

```
['Names\tLucas']
Names   Lucas
```

What's a way to do this.

Comment: What exact output are you looking for? Your question is quite unclear.

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#data-structures).  The first method is `.append`.  The code posted is broken and the output is incorrect for the code shown.

Comment: When I do print list, I want to be able to get the same output when I do the print(string)

Comment: What does that have to do with the title question? Edit the question to make it reproducible and clear what you want, or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to print the *list items* themselves, instead of the list.

By iteration:

```
>>> list1 = []
>>> string1 = "Names:\tLucas"
>>> string2 = "Names:\tJohn"
>>>
>>> list1.append(string1)
>>> list1.append(string2)
>>> 
>>> for item in list1:
...   print(item)
... 
Names:  Lucas
Names:  John
```

By [unpacking the list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3480184/2745495):

```
>>> list1 = []
>>> string1 = "Names:\tLucas"
>>> string2 = "Names:\tJohn"
>>>
>>> list1.append(string1)
>>> list1.append(string2)
>>>
>>> print(*list1, sep='\n')
Names:  Lucas
Names:  John
```

Answer (score -2):

try something like this

```
print("{}".format(string))
```