# manipulate file and join by two different character symbols

Tags: python

consider the tab-separated file `foo.txt`:

```
chrY    1208806 1208908 +   .
chrY    1212556 1212620 +   .
chrY    1465479 1466558 +   .
```

The goal is to manipulate `foo.txt` to obtain `result.txt` as such:

```
chrY:1208806-1208908
chrY:1212556-1212620
chrY:1465479-1466558
```

What I can achieve is only joining by one specific separator not two different ones --> my code:

```
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        l = line.split()[0:3]
        result = ':'.join(l)
        print(result)
```

My outcome:

```
chrY:1208806:1208908
chrY:1212556:1212620
chrY:1465479:1466558
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        l = line.split()[0:3]
        result = f'{l[0]}:{l[1]}-{l[2]}'
        print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution you can try out,

```
with open(file_name, "r") as f:
    for l in f.readlines():
        print("{0}:{1}-{2}".format(*l.split()[:3]))
```

---

```
chrY:1208806-1208908
chrY:1212556-1212620
chrY:1465479-1466558
```

Comment: what is `*` doing in `*l.split()[:3])` ? expanding ?

Comment: yes `*` is for unpacking, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3480190/4985099

Comment: why using `readlines` ? for a large file it gets slow. nice for the unpacking though.