# What's a better way to write this code. Does it contain bad practices?

Tags: python

```
list_op = [
            method1(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5),
            method2(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5),
            method3(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5),
            method4(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5),
        ]
```

I have the above but I can't help but feel like it looks like a duplicate code or it's violating some best practices. What should I do here?

Comment: Maybe putting the arguments in a tuple and [unpacking them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3480184/10077)?

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow. For improving working code, you can ask on [codereview.se] instead, but first please read [their How to Ask page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask); for example, you need to provide context.

Comment: There are [No Best Practices](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164)

Comment: In this case ... it is a matter of opinion whether a small amount of repetitious code is better or worse than a small amount of complexity to avoid writing repetitious code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
methods = [method1, method2, method3, method4]
args = [arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4]
list_op = [m(*args) for m in methods]
```